# Regex not detecting all occurrences

Tags: php, regex

The following php code only detects some of the patterns

```
$re = "/([aeiou]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]+[aeiou]+)/"; 
$str = "miniature"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This shows the following results: 'inia' and 'ure'

```
(Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => inia [1] => ure ) [1] => Array ( [0] => inia [1] => ure ) ))
```

Why is it not showing 'iatu' (any number of vowels followed by any numbers of consonant followed by any number of vowels)

How would I write the regex to give me all three results?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `iatu` to be captured, then use a positive lookahead,

```
(?=([aeiou]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]+[aeiou]+))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sK5tC5/1)

Comment: +1 from my side for quick answer. I was just updating my post.

Comment: actually, any way we can drop the match for the 'atu' (which was actually discovered by 'iatu')?

Comment: +1 for nice answer about overlapping matches, it's an advanced technique. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it not showing 'iatu'

because that is captured already by previous match `inia`

It returns two matches.

```
inia
ure
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sZ2lP5/1)

Comment: Thanks. What about "How would I write the regex to give me all three results? "